# Spring security error occured processing XML

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have this  Error :

```
Error occured processing XML org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setSource(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;'. See 
 Error Log for more details
```

This my **security.xm**l:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.4.xsd">

    <!--  Déclaration du PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -->


<!--  Déclaration de la DATASOURCE -->

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app_logistique" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>
<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" filters="none"/>  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logo*" filters="none"/>  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/objis.css" filters="none"/>  
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_PARTICIPANT,ROLE_FORMATEUR,ROLE_MAINTENANCE,ROLE_COMMERCIAL"/>
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="ROLE_COMMERCIAL"/>
        <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>  
</security:http>
<security:authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService' />

<bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT  username, password, enabled 
                                                 FROM users WHERE username = ?"/>
  <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT username, authority 
                                                       FROM authorities WHERE username = ?"/>
</bean>  


</beans>
```

Comment: Please paste your error log and ApplicationContext.xml

Comment: this is my error org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionBuilder.setSource(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionBuilder;

Comment: It says see error log for more details. Find the other log output